# Gradle include Query Files

Tags: gradle

I have query files in same location as my classes. But gradle is not copying query files into classes directory after compiling. I added following below, but it did not work. Can you help how to resolve this issue?

I can't refactor to move query files.

```
 processResources {
        from('src/main/java') {
            include  '**/*.properties'
        }
    }
```

The follow structure

```
src
  service
     service1
        Service.java
        Service.properties
```

I want that the output generated by gradle would be

```
classes
   service
        service1
          Service.class
          Service.properties
```

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: It does not copy query files to classes folder.

Comment: Who cares about classes folder? I think the name "classes" should be a bit of a giveaway what that folder is for :) It's the jar that matters (and the test classpath)

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is `src/service/service1/Service.properties` it is quite obvious why nothing is copied if you copy from `src/main/java`, isn't it?

Besides that, it might be better to configure `sourceSets { main { resources { ... } } }` instead of configuring the `processResources` task.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle and Maven both use the same sensible convention

- src/main/java is for java files ONLY
- src/main/resources is for resources (eg properties, xml, images etc)

I suggest you stick to these very sensible conventions. Both Gradle and Maven can be configured to allow resources in `src/main/java` but this should be avoided if at all possible.

Don't mess with a default!

If you really want resources in `src/main/java` then I suggest you do

```
processResources {
    from('src/main/java') {
        exclude '**/*.java'
    }
}
```